# Implement cursor function as pagination in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I have film table with 1000+ rows. I need to get 5 rows each time I call the psql function. In a function I will have arguments if arguments is empty it should return first 5 rows else next 5 rows with argument I passed

```
code  |          title          | did | date_prod  |   kind   |  len
-------+-------------------------+-----+------------+----------+-------
 BL101 | The Third Man           | 101 | 1949-12-23 | Drama    | 01:44
 BL102 | The African Queen       | 101 | 1951-08-11 | Romantic | 01:43
 JL201 | Une Femme est une Femme | 102 | 1961-03-12 | Romantic | 01:25
 P_301 | Vertigo                 | 103 | 1958-11-14 | Action   | 02:08
 P_302 | Becket                  | 103 | 1964-02-03 | Drama    | 02:28

create or replace function get_giusers_batch(code)
   returns void as $$
declare 
    user_batch record;
     giusers cursor 
         for select *
         from giuser;
begin
   -- open the cursor
   open giusers(code);
    
   
-- fetch row into the film
  user_batch := fetch FORWARD 10 FROM giusers;
-- exit when no more row to fetch
  exit when not found;

 
   
  
   -- close the cursor
   close giusers;

   return user_batch;
end; $$
```

Comment: Create a cursor, then have the function fetch 5 rows from that cursor.

Comment: `BEGIN WORK;

DECLARE films_cur SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM film;

-- Fetch the first 5 rows in the cursor films_cur:
 fetch FORWARD 10 FROM films_cur;

-- Close the cursor and end the transaction:
CLOSE films_cur;

COMMIT WORK;`

@LaurenzAlbe this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to paginate, you mean user interaction. You cannot keep a transaction open during that, so you need a `WITH HOLD` cursor. For that, you need dynamic SQL in PL/pgSQL. It is important that the cursor is explicitly closed!

Here is an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION get_data(arg integer) RETURNS SETOF uni
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE CALLED ON NULL INPUT AS
$$BEGIN
   IF arg IS NOT NULL THEN
      /* make sure cursor is closed */
      BEGIN
         EXECUTE 'CLOSE get_data_cur';
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN invalid_cursor_name THEN
            NULL;  /* ignore */
      END;

      /* declare and open cursor */
      EXECUTE format(
                 E'DECLARE get_data_cur CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR\n'
                 'SELECT id FROM uni\n'
                 'WHERE id > %s',
                 arg
              );
   END IF;

   /* return next five rows */
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'FETCH 5 FROM get_data_cur';

   /* close cursor when we are done */
   IF NOT FOUND THEN
      EXECUTE 'CLOSE get_data_cur';
   END IF;
END;$$;
```